# i have create the api but i need the standard json format

Tags: php, json, api

I have the following code in php

```
$res=array(
      'id'=>'1001',    
      'book'=> 'bname'  
      );
echo json_encode($res);
```

I expect the following output

```
{
   "data":{
      "id":"1001",
      "book":"bname",
      }
```

}

Comment: What output do you currently get? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Why would you expect `json_encode` to magically add `{"data": ... }` around what you told it to output?

Answer (score 1):

`json_encode` won't magically add a `{"data": ...}` wrapper around what you told it to output.

If you want that wrapper, you'll have to supply it:

```
$res=array(
      'id'=>'1001',    
      'book'=> 'bname'  
      );
echo json_encode(array(
    'data' => $res
));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this its work for you....its gives output which you want

```
$res=array(
      'id'=>'1001',    
      'book'=> 'bname'  
      );
      $response = array("data"=>$res);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use These Code To Get That Output.

```
<?php

$res=array('data'=>[
            'id'=>'1001',    
            'book'=> 'bname'  
        ]
      );
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```